# Compare Text Field to Custom Setting Values

Tags: apex, customsetting

I have the below line that compares 2 text fields on a custom object to see if they contain specific values:

```
 if(Object.Notes__c != null && (Object.Notes__c.contains('Value1') || 
    Object.Notes__c.contains('Value2')))
```

However, now I want to change the statement to see if the text entered in the Notes__c field on my custom object contains any of the values set in CustomSetting1. How would i go about that?

I've tried the following, but I'm not sure if this is right or will give me all the values in my custom setting:

```
List<Keywords__c> custSet = Keywords__c.Getall().Values();
        string keyWords=custSet[0].Name;

for(Object__c Object : Trigger.New){
     if(Object.Notes__c != null && Object.Notes__c.contains(keyWords))...
```

Comment: What have you tried? Where are you stuck?

Comment: I updated my post above with what I have tried, but I'm not sure if it's correct.

Comment: No. It compiles without error, but nothing happens on the record. My setting is a list setting with 8 different values. I am trying to compare a text field on a record to see if that field contains any of the values in my custom setting. If so, a checkbox is set to True on the parent record.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the Name field of the custom setting represents the value to be used to check against ...

```
Map<String,Keywords__c> keywordsByName = Keywords__c.getAll(); // get map
for (Object__c o : Trigger.New) {
    if (keywordsByName.keyset().contains(o.Notes__c)) ... // check set for membership
}
```

Comment: Great, that worked!  Thanks so much!